# dladdr: pointer-to-function vs pointer-to-object

Tags: c++, c, pointers, language-lawyer

Hopefully this is rather a simple C++ question (not a language-lawyer one).

How is one supposed to use the GNU extension `dladdr` in C++ ? Typically one would write the following in C:

```
#ifndef _GNU_SOURCE
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#endif
#include <dlfcn.h>

static void where_am_i() {}

int main()
{
  Dl_info info;
  dladdr( (void*)&where_am_i, &info );

  return 0;
}
```

However using clang one can see the cast may be invalid:

```
$ clang --version
Debian clang version 3.6.2-3 (tags/RELEASE_362/final) (based on LLVM 3.6.2)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
$ clang -Wpedantic -o foo foo.cpp -ldl
foo.cpp:11:11: warning: cast between pointer-to-function and pointer-to-object is an extension [-Wpedantic]
  dladdr( (void*)&where_am_i, &info );
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
```

The warning seems legitimate to me, so is there a way to work around that ?

Comment: No, that's a general limitation of the "dl" API. It packages function pointers into void pointers in a way that is not guaranteed to work by the C standard, but Posix requires void pointers to be able to hold function pointers (and the "dl" functions are part of Posix).

Comment: Better to write it like this: `void* p; /* dl... */ *reinterpret_cast<void**>(&where_am_i) = p;`

Comment: Just to make sure: We're talking about C++ code here, C++14 I'd guess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard way to portably convert a function pointer to `void*`. As such, there is no standard way to portably use `dladdr`. Prior to C++11, such conversion was ill-formed (I don't have the document available, but the warning by clang suggests it). Since C++11 however, the conversion is conditionally supported:

[[expr.reinterpret.cast]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#8)/8 (standard draft)

> Converting a function pointer to an object pointer type or vice versa is conditionally-supported. The meaning of such a conversion is implementation-defined, except that if an implementation supports conversions in both directions, converting a prvalue of one type to the other type and back, possibly with different cv-qualification, shall yield the original pointer value.

---

Since you are already relying on the c library extension that provides `dladdr`, you might as well rely on the language extension that lets you cast function pointer to `void*`. In that case, you may want to ask the compiler to not warn about using language extensions by compiling without the `-Wpedantic` option - or use a standard version where the conversion is at least conditionally supported. If the conversion isn't supported, then so isn't `dladdr`.